# How can one html form input field update two Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have two models, Region and Room. One room can only be in one region but one region can have many rooms. When the user is creating a room (createRoom view), I want them to enter a region, which should both update the Region model and also assign this Region to the room.

models.py

```
class Region(models.Model):
    region = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    etc....

class Room(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    etc....
```

forms.py

```
class RoomForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ['region', etc....]

class RegionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Region
        fields = ['country', 'region']
```

views.py

```
def createRoom(request):
    form_room = RoomForm()
    form_region = RegionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_room = RoomForm(request.POST)
        form_region = RegionForm(request.POST)
        if form_room.is_valid() and form_region.is_valid():
            room = form_room.save(commit=False)
            region = form_region.save(commit=False)
            room.region = region.region
            room.save()
            region.save()
            return redirect ('home')
```

template.html

```
          <form class="form" action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form_room.media}}

            <div class="form__group">
              <label for="region_name">Region</label>
              {{form_region.region}}
            </div>


</form>
```

The line **room.region = region.region** in *views.py* I was hoping would set the region object of the Region model as the region object of the Room model. I receive no errors when submitting the form. However the Room model's region object stays empty.

---

I updated my views to check for errors and the error seems to be that the forms are not valid:

```
def createRoom(request):
    form_room = RoomForm()
    form_region = RegionForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_room = RoomForm(request.POST)
        form_region = RegionForm(request.POST)
        if form_room.is_valid() and form_region.is_valid():
            room = form_room.save(commit=False)
            region = form_region.save(commit=False)
            room.host = request.user
            room.region = region.region.pk
            region.save()
            room.save()
        #return redirect ('home')
        else:
                messages.error(request, 'form not valid')
```

Answer (score 2):

Im assuming that since you are creating two models in one form, order plays a big role here. You are trying to save `room` with a `ForeignKey` `region` when this model instance does not exist. Try swapping the order:

```
region.save()
room.save()
```

That way you first save the `Region` and then the data in the `Room` is not empty. Also try using `try except:` for better error handling. Finally keep in mind that `ForeignKey` requires a **`key`** so you might need to set

```
room.region = region.pk
```

Comment: Thanks haduki! While this did not solve the issue, I took your advice on error handling and now at least know that the source error is one of the forms not being valid (see post update).

Comment: did you try printing out your post data to see what is missing?

Comment: I ran form_room.errors and it says "region Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.". I am confused because the room model says that region can have null=True.
If I remove the Room model's region field from the form, both forms get saved but the Room model's region field stays empty. thanks for the help so far, do you have any more ideas?

Comment: did you try using the pk as instructed in the answer?  You are not giving a value to your `form_room region` . Also print your data to see what is missing `print(dict(request.POST.items()))` and `print(RoomForm)`

Comment: Hi Haduki, region.region.pk gives an error ''str' object has no attribute 'pk''
region.region prints out all key value pairs aside of the Room model's region object. It does print the Region model's region object fine. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: its `region.pk` my bad